# Sum of Years depreciation class return issue

Tags: java, class, return

So I've been given the task to create a form that the user inputs the Acquisition Cost, the Salvage Value, and the Useful Life of an item.  I have 3 separate depreciation methods, Straight Line, Sum of Years Digit, and Double Declining.  Straight Line I have working properly but the last two are giving me the same issues on the return statements, giving the same depreciation for each year when it is supposed to vary (I was given an example of the outcome). Below is the section of the class for the Sum of Years and the public variables for the entire class.  Following that is the private double that gives the return statement.

Variables:

```
    public class DepreciationScheduleClass {
    NumberFormat money = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    // the schedule is just an array of formatted strings
    public String[] schedule;
    int period;
```

Method:

```
    public void MakeSumOfYearsDigitSchedule(double acquisitionCost, 
    double salvageValue, int usefulLife)
{        
    double totalDepreciation = 0.0;
    double undepreciatedAmount = acquisitionCost;
    double depreciation = SYD(acquisitionCost,salvageValue,usefulLife,period);

    String scheduleLine;

    schedule = new String[usefulLife + 2];

    // add period 0 to schedule
    scheduleLine = "0\t " + money.format(depreciation) + "  \t  " 
            + money.format(undepreciatedAmount); 
    schedule[0] = scheduleLine;

    //add period lines to schedule
    for (int i = 1; i <= usefulLife; i++)
    {
        totalDepreciation = totalDepreciation + depreciation;
        undepreciatedAmount = acquisitionCost - totalDepreciation;
        scheduleLine = i + "\t " + money.format(depreciation) + "  \t  " 
            + money.format(undepreciatedAmount);
        schedule[i] = (scheduleLine);
    }

    //add total depreciation line to schedule
    schedule[usefulLife + 1] = "Total depreciated \t" + 
            money.format(totalDepreciation);
}
```

The private double with return:

```
    private double SYD(double acquisitionCost, 
        double salvageValue, int usefulLife, int period)
{  
    double SOYlife=(usefulLife*(usefulLife+1))/2; 
    return ((usefulLife-period)/SOYlife)*(acquisitionCost-salvageValue);
}
```

I honestly think I'm just missing something incredibly simple but I've gone over it again and again and I need another pair of eyes and brain to take a look.  Thanks in advanced!

Edit

Sorry for the confusion.  Still new at this.

This is what I'm getting.
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbvFL.jpg

And this is what I'm supposed to be getting.
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPDQO.jpg

What I think is causing me the problem is the private double that gives the return statement.

Comment: Could you clarify what you are getting and what you should be and which methods are causing the problem?  its a little unclear

Comment: Flagged as unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Where are your methods for Sum of Years Digit, and Double Declining.

Comment: @Petro the method above (middle section code) is the Sum of Years Digit. I didn't put the Double Declining up because I believe it is the same issue as this one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate your deprecation in you loop based on (acquisitionCost - totalDepreciation) instead of acquisitionCost only. That's why the deprecation gets lower every year.